# Trying to move husky robot with teleop_twist_keyboard

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just started to learn ROS, and I'm following the course: [Programming for Robotics](http://www.rsl.ethz.ch/education-students/lectures/ros.html).

In Lecture 1, they asked to run Husky simulator package. I'm using ROS Lunar version, so I've had to compile it. In fact, I have had to compile all of these packages:

- geographic_info
- husky
- interactive_marker_twist_server
- lms1xx
- robot_localization
- ros_control
- teleop_twist_keyboard
- twist_mux
- unique_identifier

I have created this launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
   <include file="$(find husky_gazebo)/launch/husky_empty_world.launch" >
      <arg name="world_name" value="/usr/share/gazebo-7/worlds/robocup14_spl_field.world" />
   </include>

   <node name="teleop" pkg="teleop_twist_keyboard" type="teleop_twist_keyboard.py" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

Bur, when I try to move the robot with the keyboard, selecting the terminal where I have launched the launch file, it doesn't. It only appears this on terminal window:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /ekf_localization/base_link_frame: base_link
 * /ekf_localization/frequency: 50
 * /ekf_localization/imu0: imu/data
 * /ekf_localization/imu0_config: [False, False, Fa...
 * /ekf_localization/imu0_differential: True
 * /ekf_localization/imu0_queue_size: 10
 * /ekf_localization/imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: True
 * /ekf_localization/odom0: husky_velocity_co...
 * /ekf_localization/odom0_config: [False, False, Fa...
 * /ekf_localization/odom0_differential: False
 * /ekf_localization/odom0_queue_size: 10
 * /ekf_localization/odom_frame: odom
 * /ekf_localization/two_d_mode: True
 * /ekf_localization/world_frame: odom
 * /gazebo/enable_ros_network: True
 * /husky_joint_publisher/publish_rate: 50
 * /husky_joint_publisher/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /husky_velocity_controller/angular/z/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /husky_velocity_controller/angular/z/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /husky_velocity_controller/angular/z/max_acceleration: 6.0
 * /husky_velocity_controller/angular/z/max_velocity: 2.0
 * /husky_velocity_controller/base_frame_id: base_link
 * /husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel_timeout: 0.25
 * /husky_velocity_controller/enable_odom_tf: False
 * /husky_velocity_controller/estimate_velocity_from_position: False
 * /husky_velocity_controller/left_wheel: ['front_left_whee...
 * /husky_velocity_controller/linear/x/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /husky_velocity_controller/linear/x/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /husky_velocity_controller/linear/x/max_acceleration: 3.0
 * /husky_velocity_controller/linear/x/max_velocity: 1.0
 * /husky_velocity_controller/pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0....
 * /husky_velocity_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /husky_velocity_controller/right_wheel: ['front_right_whe...
 * /husky_velocity_controller/twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0....
 * /husky_velocity_controller/type: diff_drive_contro...
 * /husky_velocity_controller/velocity_rolling_window_size: 2
 * /husky_velocity_controller/wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0
 * /husky_velocity_controller/wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.875
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: lunar
 * /rosversion: 1.13.6
 * /twist_mux/locks: [{'topic': 'e_sto...
 * /twist_mux/topics: [{'topic': 'joy_t...
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    base_controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
    ekf_localization (robot_localization/ekf_localization_node)
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    spawn_husky_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)
    teleop (teleop_twist_keyboard/teleop_twist_keyboard.py)
    twist_marker_server (interactive_marker_twist_server/marker_server)
    twist_mux (twist_mux/twist_mux)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [25984]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 2bffeb0c-8126-11e8-bd69-fcaa149ccb50
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [25997]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [26015]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [26026]
process[base_controller_spawner-4]: started with pid [26031]
process[ekf_localization-5]: started with pid [26032]
process[twist_marker_server-6]: started with pid [26033]
process[robot_state_publisher-7]: started with pid [26034]
process[twist_mux-8]: started with pid [26054]
process[spawn_husky_model-9]: started with pid [26072]
process[teleop-10]: started with pid [26106]
[ INFO] [1530886158.885034522]: [twist_marker_server] Initialized.
[ INFO] [1530886159.102619925]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1530886159.102823160]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1530886159.123702779]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1530886159.124722013]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...

Reading from the keyboard  and Publishing to Twist!
---------------------------
Moving around:
   u    i    o
   j    k    l
   m    ,    .

For Holonomic mode (strafing), hold down the shift key:
---------------------------
   U    I    O
   J    K    L
   M    <    >

t : up (+z)
b : down (-z)

anything else : stop

q/z : increase/decrease max speeds by 10%
w/x : increase/decrease only linear speed by 10%
e/c : increase/decrease only angular speed by 10%

CTRL-C to quit

currently:  speed 0.5   turn 1.0
```

The rqt_graph is:

[image: image description]

With nodes and topics:
[image: image description]

rosnode list is:

```
/ekf_localization
/gazebo
/gazebo_gui
/robot_state_publisher
/rosout
/teleop
/twist_marker_server
/twist_mux
```

rostopic list is:

```
/clock
/cmd_vel
/diagnostics
/e_stop
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/gazebo_gui/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo_gui/parameter_updates
/husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel
/husky_velocity_controller/odom
/imu/data
/joint_states
/joy_teleop/cmd_vel
/odometry/filtered
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/set_pose
/tf
/tf_static
/twist_marker_server/cmd_vel
/twist_marker_server/feedback
/twist_marker_server/update
/twist_marker_server/update_full
```

What is wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I get this warning:

```
[WARN] [1530902387.083562, 14.437000]: Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
```

I have tried this:

```
rosservice list | grep controller_manager
```

With no output.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296539/trying-to-move-husky-robot-with-teleop_twist_keyboard/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-07-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akash Purandare](https://answers.ros.org/users/34280/akash-purandare/) on 2018-07-06**:
Can you go to the nodes only drop down, select Nodes and Topics and send the screenshot of that window?

**Comment by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on 2018-07-06**:
@AkashPurandare I have added the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Did you send a command for the desired velocity ? if not, just open another tab on your terminal and run:

rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '[2.0,0.0,0.0]' '[5.0,1.0,0.0]'.

The numbers in the arg are arbitrary, you can try yours depending on the linear and angular velocity you need.

---

Originally posted by [imraj](https://answers.ros.org/users/36343/imraj/) with karma: 16 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0